# How can I create a dockable window in WPF (C#)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, window

Let's say you have a view (userControl) with its own XAML code, and another window (window) also with its own XAML code. Is there any way to be able to dock this window into the view (the view will rearrange the UI to accomodate the docked window), but also get the window out of the view if you want to move the window around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [AvalonDock](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/) project.

> AvalonDock is a docking windows control for WPF that lets you create
>   customizable layouts using a full featured window docking system
>   similar to what is found in many popular integrated development
>   environements (IDEs) such as Visual Studio. It includes themes and
>   samples to get you started.

Example of usage:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:avalonDock="http://avalondock.codeplex.com"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="434" Width="684">
    <Grid>
        <avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="dockingManager">
            <avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
                <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane/>
                    <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane DockWidth="150">
                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Sample Tool Pane">
                            <TextBox/>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
                <avalonDock:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>
                    <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorSide>
                        <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                            <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable Title="Autohidden Content">
                                <TextBox/>
                            </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                    </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorSide>
                </avalonDock:LayoutRoot.LeftSide>
            </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Documentation you can find [here](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/documentation).

Comment: namespace xmlns:avalonDock has problem

Comment: @aaron what kind of problem ?